# Android - how do I delete a room in Firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an chat application and I'm just in the beginning. I have an activity that the user can open a chat room and also delete. My problem is with the delete. I can successfully delete the chat room from the list, but I don't know how to delete it from the Firebase.
The problem is that I'm using longclick , I mean if the user want to remove a chatroom he need to tap on the chatroom but a long click, and then the delete option pop up. and then he press the button "delete" and delete it from the list.

**the chat room code**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button createChat;
private EditText chatRoomName;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> listOfChats = new ArrayList<>();
private String name;
private DatabaseReference root  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       ifUserIsLoggedIn(); // Method that checks if the user is logged in. if not, it will take the
                           // user to Login Activity
    createChat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.createChatBtn);
    chatRoomName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.chatRoomEt);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, listOfChats);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        // this method delete a chat room after a long click when "delete" button press
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch(item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.delete:
            arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(info.position));
            root.removeValue(arrayAdapter.getItem(info.position));

    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

on the `public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`
    method gets the id of the list and delete it from the list.
but i dont know how to delete it from the firebase. in the firebase i save it as a root. if a code is missing please let me know so i can upload more code

**EDITED - Create chat Code**

```
    createChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(chatRoomName.getWindowToken(),0);

            // send to the fire base the data. it sends only the name of the room, with no any key.
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put(chatRoomName.getText().toString(), "");
            root.updateChildren(map);
            chatRoomName.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just does not compile using firebase 9.8. Then it cannot work because you refer an item of your adapter just after having deleted it. Finally I think you should not remove the chat room from the adapter before Firebase has confirmed the removal.

It's difficult to give a 100% correct answer because you don't show the code that creates a chat room. Anyway I make here the assumption that the chat rooms are children under root. Try this :

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.delete:

            final String chatRoomToDelete = arrayAdapter.getItem(info.position)
            root.child(chatRoomToDelete).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if (databaseError == null) {
                        arrayAdapter.remove(chatRoomToDelete);
                    } else {
                        // show databaseError to user
                    }
                }
            });

    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: OK I think my code should work then - did you try it ?